# Is it possible to buffer only a specified segment of a video file using MediaElement in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, mediaelement

I have a scenario where I have to play certain segment from multiple video files. When I am trying to achieve it the complete video gets buffered into my temp folder. Because the files that I am using are very large files(> 500MB), it is taking time to buffer and during buffering playback is not smooth. Since I only have to play a small segment from the video, is it possible to buffer only the specified segment and not the complete file?